# Bigquery: "table_a" Union all "table_b" and Left Join "table_b" with "mappingstation" table

Tags: google-bigquery

This is my first time working with sql/bigquery. I cannot explain the problem clearly because I don't understand the logic of sql.

I have 'table_a' which I would like to union with 'table_b' then query "TransactionType", "BusinessDay", and "ExitStationID". However, in 'table_b' the "ExitStationID" is "SiteID" which I need to Left Join with 'MP_001_Station' table.

I can query both table. However, the ExitStationID that belongs to 'table_b' isn't converted to the right value.

Here's the code:

```
WITH bss AS (
  SELECT
    TransactionType,
    BusinessDay,
    ExitStationID
  FROM
    `table_a`
  WHERE
  EntryStationID IS NOT NULL AND ExitStationID IS NOT NULL AND
  CAST(EntryStationID as INT64) < 100 AND CAST(ExitStationID AS INT64) < 100 AND
  BusinessDay BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-12-31'

  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    CAST(MessageTypeValue AS STRING) AS TransactionType,
    BusinessDay,
    SiteID AS ExitStationID
  FROM
    `table_b`
  WHERE
  MessageTypeValue = 20 AND BusinessDay BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-12-31'
),

dimdate AS (
  SELECT
    EnglishDayNameOfWeek AS Day,
    DayType,
    FullDateAlternateKey
  FROM
    `DimDate`
),

dimstation AS (
  SELECT
    LineCode AS ExitLine,
    StationKey
  FROM
    `DimStation`
),

mappingstation AS (
  SELECT
    StationCodeBLU
  FROM 
    `MP_001_Station`
),

legacy AS (
  SELECT
    SiteID
  FROM `table_b`
)

SELECT 
  EXTRACT(DAYOFYEAR FROM BusinessDay) AS DayOfYear,
  EXTRACT(DATE FROM BusinessDay) AS Date,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM BusinessDay) AS Month,
  Day,
  DayType,
  ExitStationID,
  COUNT(*) AS Ridership

FROM bss
LEFT JOIN dimdate
ON (
  CAST(bss.BusinessDay AS date) = dimdate.FullDateAlternateKey
)

LEFT JOIN dimstation
ON (
  CAST(bss.ExitStationID AS INT64) = CAST(dimstation.StationKey AS INT64)
)

LEFT JOIN mappingstation
ON (
  CAST(bss.ExitStationID AS INT64) = CAST(mappingstation.StationCodeBLU AS INT64)
)

GROUP BY
  DayOfYear,
  Date,
  Month,
  Day,
  DayType,
  ExitStationID

ORDER BY
  DayOfYear,
  ExitStationID
```

Comment: Can you add some dummy data for the tables and what the expected output is in that case

Comment: @Thanawat Raibroycharoen, I see you are casting ExitStationID as INT64, however what is happening when you say that _"it isn't converted right"_?

Comment: thanks to both sramalingam24 and Alexandre Moraes. I didn't check your reply. But I've already solved the problem.